# JavaScript básico, validar cadena sin espacios

Tags: javascript, html

Buenos dias! Estoy hace unas horas pensando y no se donde se encuentra el error, tengo que validar que un nombre no contenga espacios!

```js
function validarNombre(){
    var p1 = document.getElementById("nombre").value;  //tomamos en una variable lo ingresado en el login nombre
    
    var espacios = false;
    var cont = 0;
    
    while (!espacios && (cont < p1.length)) {
     if (p1.charAt(cont) == " "){ 
     espacios = true;
     cont++;
     }
    }
    
    if (espacios) { 
     alert ("La contraseña no puede contener espacios en blanco"); 
     return false; 
    }
    
    
    
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <center><p class="usuario">Usuarios </p></center>
      <div class="login">
       <form name="login" method="post" action="#">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label><br>
         <input type="text" onSubmit="return validarNombre()" id="nombre" name="nombre" value=""><br>
        <label for="correo">Email:</label><br>
         <input type="correo" name="correo" value=""><br>
    
       <a href="#"> Suscribite Ahora </a>
    
        <p class="submit" onclick="" > 
        <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
    
       </form>
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: La contraseña o el nombre es el que no debe contener espacios?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hola tu código no es eficiente al comprobar caracter por caracter si tiene o no espacios, puedes usar regex o expresión regular, como esta para comprobarlo:

```
var p1 = document.getElementById("nombre").value;  //tomamos en una variable lo ingresado en el login nombre

var noValido = /\s/;

if(noValido.test(p1)){ // se chequea el regex de que el string no tenga espacio
     alert ("La contraseña no puede contener espacios en blanco"); 
    return false; 
}
else{
     alert ("Ok"); 
    return false; 
}
```

Como se menciona en los comentarios el código de arriba hace match con espacios, tab entre otros. Si solo se busca espacio hacerlo de la forma

```
var p1 = document.getElementById("nombre").value;  //tomamos en una variable lo ingresado en el login nombre

var noValido = / /;

if(noValido.test(p1)){ // se chequea el regex de que el string no tenga espacio
     alert ("La contraseña no puede contener espacios en blanco"); 
    return false; 
}
else{
     alert ("Ok"); 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Esta debiera ser marcada como la respuesta correcta @IbarraEmiliano

Comment: @amenadiel no te preocupes, igual queda para que sea consultado por otros.

Comment: Esto no sólo coincide con un espacio, también coincide con tab, salto de página, salto de línea y enter. No es lo que se preguntó. La expresión regular que coincide con un espacio es `/ /`

Comment: Cierto, "white space is more than a white space" dicen. Se podría comprobar usando `/\x20/` o `/\u0020/`.

Comment: @Mariano tienes toda la razón, en este caso creo que de igual forma le sirve al usuario que preguntó, de igual forma dentro de un rato hago el update a la respuesta con ambos tipos.

Comment: @Wilfredo lo sé, seguramente sea más útil. Pero es habitual que se considere a `\s` sólo como espacio. Por eso me parecía bueno para otros lectores si podías aclararlo... Gracias por considerarlo.

Answer (score 12):

> Nota: La solución basada en expresiones regulares también es válida, pero las expresiones regulares están pensadas para casos mas complejos. En tu caso que es mucho mas sencillo y específico `indexOf()` hace lo mismo con un mejor rendimiento.

No necesitas reiventar la rueda, si deseas verificar  si un caracter existe o no dentro de una cadena utiliza la función `.indexOf()`.

Si el resultado es -1 indica que la cadena pasada como parámetro (en tu caso " ") no ha sido encontrado en la cadena original. De lo contrario devuelve la posición donde se encontró la primera ocurrencia.

Ejemplo

```js
function verificar() {
    console.clear();
    
    let cadena = document.getElementById("cadena").value;

    if (cadena.indexOf(" ") === -1) {
        console.log(`\"${cadena}\" no contiene espacios`);
    } else {
        console.log(`\"${cadena}\" contiene al menos un espacio`);
    }
}
```

```html
Ingresa un valor: <input id="cadena" type="text"> <button onClick="verificar()">Verificar</button>
```

En tu caso el código puede quedar así

```
function validarNombre() {
    if (document.getElementById("nombre").value.indexOf(" ") !== -1) {
        alert("La contraseña no puede contener espacios en blanco");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: también es correcto. Upvote para ti. ¿Ahora todos los browsers aceptan backticks para template literals?

Comment: Al menos en las últimas versiones Chrome, Firefox y Edge desktop

Comment: Pero si usa regex podría añadir otras comprobaciones al campo en una sola línea: por ejemplo no admitir más que letras, números y guiones (amazon AWS tiene esa regla para nombrar instancias, VPC, balanceadores, buckets, etc)

Comment: No es bueno juntar todas las comprabaciones en una única línea, siempre debe separarse en varias validaciones para poder mostrar un mensaje de error personalizado por cada uno.

Comment: No veo el por qué. Si el texto dice: "sólo se admiten letras, números y guiones", el mensaje de error no tiene por qué ser: "su texto contiene una ñ, recuerde que debe contener sólo letras, números y guiones". Para ese caso mejor poner "oiga, aprenda a leer, dijimos letras, números y guiones".

Answer (score 6):

Tienes un loop infinito

```
function validarNombre(){
  var p1 = document.getElementById("nombre").value; 
  var espacios = false;
  var cont = 0;

  while (!espacios && (cont < p1.length)) {
    if (p1.charAt(cont) == " "){ 
    espacios = true;
    cont++; // Esto nunca ocurre!!
    }
  }

  if (espacios) { 
    alert ("La contraseña no puede contener espacios en blanco"); 
    return false; 
  }
  return true;
}
```

Debiera ser

```
function validarNombre(){
  var p1 = document.getElementById("nombre").value; 
  var espacios = false;
  var cont = 0;

  while (!espacios && (cont < p1.length)) {
    if (p1.charAt(cont) == " "){ 
      espacios = true;
    }
    cont++; // Esto sí ocurre 
  }

  if (espacios) { 
    alert ("La contraseña no puede contener espacios en blanco"); 
    return false; 
  }
  return true;
}
```

Te respondo esto para que salgas de la interrogante acerca de por qué no funciona. Sin embargo, **la respuesta de Wilfredo es la manera correcta de hacer esta comprobación**. Aprende expresiones regulares, te van a simplificar la vida. Aunque...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buena explicación, hasta que llegué al último párrafo... Hace muchos años que trabajo con regex, y odio ese comic (nadie que programe en Perl debería quejarse de regex, creo que es una adaptación barata de otra frase famosa ["*now you have two problems*"](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)... Pero no creo que regex sea la mejor solución, [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf) está para eso.

Comment: Pienso que el chiste proviene del fenómeno llamado `Maslow's Hammer`. Eres experto en una herramienta y quieres usarla para todo. Luego a alguien se le ocurre parsear XML con regex y le explota el cerebro.

Answer (score 5):

Algo más sencillo y sin usar regex, es hacer un split y contar la cantidad de valores que se encuentren, y en base a eso pasás a saber si hay o no espacios.

Admito que no es la gran solución, pero es algo básico y rápido de programar.

Ejemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var nombre   = "john doe";
    var data     = nombre.split(" ");
    var palabras = data.length;

    if (palabras > 1) {
        console.log("Hay espacios.");
    } else {
        console.log("No hay espacios.");
    }

</script>
```

También, lo que podés hacer es usar `indexOf()` (como mencionan en un comentario anterior).

Ejemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var nombre   = " johndoe";

    if (nombre.indexOf(" ") > -1) {
        console.log("Hay espacios.");
    } else {
        console.log("No hay espacios.");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Otro upvote. Es válido aunque sea rudimentario.

Comment: ¿Probaste con `" juanPerez"` (con un espacio en la posición 0)?

Comment: @Skollprog, es cierto, tienes que comprobar que indexOf sea distinto a -1, no que sea mayor a 0

Comment: @Mariano, tenés razón, se me pasó por alto ese detalle. Ahí modifiqué el código.